# How to print outputs of a pretrained huggingface model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to make a classification based on a pretrained huggingface model. How do I print the output (the classification with the label)?

```
import torch as pt
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("lwachowiak/Metaphor-Detection-XLMR")

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("lwachowiak/Metaphor-Detection-XLMR")

inputs = tokenizer("The virus is an enemy", return_tensors="pt")`
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

The answer should be that "enemy" has label "1", but if I print output the answer is:

```
TokenClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=tensor([[[ 2.1014, -1.9961],
         [ 6.3821, -5.9710],
         [ 5.4977, -5.3213],
         [ 6.0334, -5.7669],
         [ 5.8730, -5.6598],
         [-1.0633,  0.7815],
         [-2.0203,  1.4977],
         [-1.3852,  0.6271],
         [ 5.8815, -5.7773]]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For token classification there ia a [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/token_classification) on huggingface that you can refer to.

In short to get the prdeiction you can simply write:

```
predictions = outputs.logits.argmax(dim=-1)
```

Hope this answers your question